# ¿Cómo separar este array de fetch_assoc()? MySQL, PHP, FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, array, fpdf, imprimir

Hola a toda la comunidad. Me acaba de surgir un problema y no he podido resolverlo. Estoy creando un archivo PDF y necesito hacer un detalle general de cada asignatura con su profesor. Deseo dividir cada sección con el profesor que ha dictado la asignatura (utilizando Cell de FPDF), es decir mostrar su nombre, listar cada asignatura, y luego pasar a otro profesor, y así hacer lo mismo con los demás. Sin embargo, al recibir la información con fetch_assoc(), voy a imprimir el campo del nombre del profesor y se me imprimen todos en una misma celda, es decir que se me imprime el campo "nombre_y_apellido" completo, no puedo dividirlo por filas.

[image: Consulta base de datos]

**Consulta SQL:**

```
$sql_taller="SELECT asig.DetalleAsignatura, plantaller.id_planilla_de_taller, prof.nombre_y_apellido, 
plantaller.Tcurso, plantaller.division, plantaller.comision, plantaller.FechaInicio, plantaller.FechaFinalizacion, 
plantaller.Bimestre, plantaller.ciclo_lectivo FROM planilla_de_taller plantaller, profesores prof, 
asignaturas asig, alumnos_por_taller alxtaller WHERE alxtaller.Id_Alumno='$id_alumno' AND 
plantaller.id_asignatura=asig.IdAsignarutas AND plantaller.Id_Profesor=prof.id_profesores AND 
alxtaller.Id_Planilla_Taller=plantaller.id_planilla_de_taller AND asig.TipoAsignatura='Taller' 
ORDER BY plantaller.FechaInicio DESC";
```

**PHP:**

```
$querytaller=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_taller);

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf -> AddPage();

    $pdf -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(0,134,255);
    $pdf->SetXY(10, 115);
    $pdf -> Cell(191.5,5,utf8_decode("3- DESEMPEÑO ESCOLAR: TALLERES"),0,1,'L',true);

while($regtaller=$querytaller->fetch_assoc()){
    $pdf-> Cell(110,5,$regtaller["nombre_y_apellido"], 1,1,'C', true);
}

$pdf -> Output('I', "legajo_alumno_$regalumnos[id_alumno]");
```

[image: PDF]

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo primero es que deberás agregar el código relevante a tu pregunta en forma de texto y no como imagen por favor

Comment: El código relevante que aparece señalado en la imagen está justo debajo de la misma

Comment: Precisamente amigo pero no para todos es cómodo visualizar el código desde una imagen, del mismo modo para replicar tu ejercicio nadie se va a poner a escribir el código desde cero, lo mejor es ponerlo como indico por si alguien lo ocupa solo lo copie

Comment: Perfecto, extendí el código y lo puse como has dicho. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a utilizando un foreach en vez del while:

```php
$querytaller=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_taller);

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf -> AddPage();

    $pdf -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(0,134,255);
    $pdf->SetXY(10, 115);
    $pdf -> Cell(191.5,5,utf8_decode("3- DESEMPEÑO ESCOLAR: TALLERES"),0,1,'L',true);

//La siguiente línea crea un array con el resultado de la consulta:
$regtaller=$querytaller->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($regtaller as $lineaDelArray){
    $pdf-> Cell(110,5,$lineaDelArray["nombre_y_apellido"], 1,1,'C', true);
}

$pdf -> Output('I', "legajo_alumno_$regalumnos[id_alumno]");
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'nombre_y_apellido' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tallerxampp\legajo.php on line 206 

Me sale ese error, como si no encontrara "nombre_y_apellido" en el array. Probé poniendo $lineaDelArray[0] y solo imprime la primer letra de cada resultado

Comment: Y si pruebas simplemente $lineaDelArray?